# Explode Request URI

Tags: php, httprequest

```
$url_current = "http://$_SERVER[HTTP_HOST]$_SERVER[REQUEST_URI]";
```

if url current return:

```
http://example.com/part1_part2_part3_part4_part5/
```

part1 to part4 is always equal in the url, part5 is variable.

How I explode request_URI and I capture part5 and put in `$variable5`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
<?php
$url = "http://example.com/part1_part2_part3_part4_part5/";// your example url
$data = parse_url($url); // parse_url() to get path data
echo "<pre/>";print_r($data); // print parse_url() data
$new_data = explode('_',$data['path']); // explode the path data only from parse_url() data 
$last_param = trim($new_data[count($new_data)-1],'/'); // remove `/` from the data and assign to a variable
echo $last_param; // print variable value
?>
```

Output:- http://prntscr.com/a9445q

Comment: Thank you @Anant it works, if I need penultimate variable only change to `-2` it´s great.